# Number of connections to database is much higher then numbers of queries, why?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, glimpse

I was watching how my application behaves with Glimpse(web diagnostic tool), and could not explain why number of connections to db is much higher then actual queries. I look at particular ajax call to db, which loads 10 more Entities to view each time list is being scrolled to bottom.
[image]

13 Queries are because of lazy loading, but i can't explain why so much connections to db (92). When I tested it on more simple application, while eager loading, there was just one connection to db, and while lazy loading #connections was equal to #queries. What can cause this behavior and how does it impact performance?

**Edit:** I'm using mysql.

Comment: SQL is a language. Specify dbms instead.

Comment: I'm using mysql in both cases, edited question, thank you for tip

Comment: Although [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65669/high-number-of-connections) on DBA SE is for SQL Server, it may be related?